# Elasticsearch aggregation over metric aggregation result values

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I would like to list something like how many users owns different quantity of products.
e.g.

```
10 users has 5 products
5 users has 4 products
8 users has 3 products
```

with given mapping

```
{
  "user_id"
  "product_id"
}
```

However, for nested aggregation function I can only find nested aggregation can "group" each bucket's  mapping field, but not bucket's stat (e.g. value_count, sum...e.t.c)
The query logic I can imagine is: (of course it doesn't work)

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "test_aggr" :{
      "terms": { "field": "user_id" },
      "aggs" : {
          "user_own_qty": {
              "value_count" : {"field" : "user_id" },
              "aggs": {
                "group_by_user_own_qty": {
                    "terms": { "field": "user_own_qty.value" },
                    "aggs": {
                        "user_qty_vs_user_own_qty": {
                            "value_count" : { "field" : "user_own_qty.value" 
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where SQL(Oracle) seems can be done easily:

```
with user_product_count as(
select user, count(product) as own_product_count
  from product
  group by user
)
select count(user), own_product count
  from user_product_count
  group by own_product_count
```

Please advise. Thanks a lot :)